# Print tree without recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have this code that print the data of each node in the tree:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data, children=[]):
        self.data = data
        self.children = children
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.data)

n1 = Node(1)
n2 = Node(2)
n3 = Node(3)
n4 = Node(4)
n5 = Node(5)
n6 = Node(6)
n7 = Node(7)


n1.children=[n2,n3,n4]
n3.children = [n5,n6]
n6.children=[n7]

def print_rec(node):
    print node
    if not node.children: return
    for c in node.children:
        printer(c)
```

how can I write the print_rec method without using recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a queue to track nodes still to process, adding to it as you process them:

```
def print_nonrec_breathfirst(node):
    queue = [node]
    while queue:
        node, queue = queue[0], queue[1:]
        print node
        for c in node.children:
            queue.append(c)
```

or you could use a stack, processing children first:

```
def print_nonrec_depthfirst(node):
    stack = [node]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        print node
        for c in node.children:
            stack.append(c)
```

Either way, you keep track of what nodes you haven't yet printed, and *as you process nodes* you *also* figure out what child nodes you still need to process.

Demo:

```
>>> print_nonrec_breathfirst(n1)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
>>> print_nonrec_depthfirst(n1)
1
4
3
6
7
5
2
```

Comment: This is works great. But is there a more "simple" (easy to master) way to do that?

Comment: @Kipi Well... recursion ;-)

Comment: `if not node.children: continue` is pointless - when `node.children` is empty list/tuple, the for's body after it simply doesn't get executed.

Comment: @Kipi: What's complicated in this solution? While there is any node to process, print one of elements, and append their childrens to list of nodes to process.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I had made a mental note to verify that it'd be an empty list then forgot. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I am understanding the solution code. But not the way to think through this kind of problems.

Comment: @Kipi: this is a fairly standard process for traversing a tree without recursion. In general you'd just know the process, you are not expected to re-invent this wheel from scratch.

Comment: Instead of print_nonrec_breathfirst you could do the same as print_nonrec_depthfirst just change the node = stack.pop() to node = stack.pop(0)

Comment: @Kipi except you'd rename it `queue`. You could also use `collections.deque`. I felt that using slicing illustrated what happens quite nicely.